# How to Create ImageBrush in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf

In XAML:

```
    <Rectangle Stroke="Aqua" Opacity="0.7" StrokeThickness="10" Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="22" Height="86" Width="102">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\xiaorui.dong\Pictures\profile.jpeg"></ImageBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

XAML works fine, but how to create the above **ImageBrush** in C# code:

C# should be like this:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.StrokeThickness = 10;
rectangle.Height = 200;
rectangle.Width = 100;
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 100d);
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 100d);
rectangle.Fill = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\xiaorui.dong\Pictures\profile.jpeg")));
```

Comment: Your code works for me with a known url, are you sure that you meant .jpeg instead of .jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is with locating the image and that the exception you're getting is because you don't provide the `UriKind` parameter. Try giving `UriKind.Relative` as a parameter to the `Uri`:

```
rectangle.Fill = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(
    new Uri(@"C:\Users\xiaorui.dong\Pictures\profile.jpeg", UriKind.Relative)));
```

Answer (score 8):

In c# you can use it like , first thing is remove the fill from XAML then use the same code in c# as you have used it . It must work.

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();

ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your path",UriKind.Relative));
rectangle.Fill = ib;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code creates ImageBrush using image "Assets/image.png" which is part of the UWP project. Relative paths are unavailable in UWP version of ImageBrush.

```
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.png"));
```

Comment: please add some explanation of your answer